# C# my datagridview column show wrong year

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Using a MySQL database:

[image]

My `DataGridView` results:

[image]

My code

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Invoices.InvoiceDate,InvoiceDetail.ProductName,InvoiceDetail.Quantity,InvoiceDetail.Discount FROM Invoices INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail ON Invoices.InvoiceID=InvoiceDetail.InvoiceID WHERE Invoices.CustomersID='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);

MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";

sda.Update(dt);
```

Comment: What happens when you don't format it? Try commenting:
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
this line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}"** for gridview.